# A few enter points in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

At first, sorry for my english. I trying to resolve problem with a few enter points (a few initializators like initWithFrame: and initWithCoder:). Not to repeat my setup code. At first i had a simple solution, just create method ("setup" for example) that called by initializators. But there is a little problem with subclasses. If my subclass have own initializator like initWithFrame:backgroundColor: and property "backgroundColor" then its own overriden "setup" will be called by super initializator but "backgroundColor" will still nil. So this "setup" will cant use this property. I think its common problem and its have nice common solution, that i cant find.Thanks.

Comment: Could you post some related code please?

Comment: I'd suggest that you read the Swift documentation on initializers in depth.   It describes all the various issues with initializers and how the language either solved the problem or made it such that your code is more defensive.   All of the patterns are applicable to Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, I'll create static function called `_commonInit(MyClass *self)` and call that from each initializer.   It is a function because it won't be inherited.

Comment: Thanks, its cool, but can you explain why this func cant be inherited?

Comment: It can be inherited as a method, if you want.  But that proves problematic in that you now have a second initialization chain and additional ordering dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

base class

```
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {
       [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setup
{
   //some setup code
}
```

child class

```
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame param:(id)param
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self)
    {
       self.param = param;
       //setup will be run by parent
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setup
{
    [super setup];
    //child setup code
    //when this code will work self.param will still nil!
}
```

thats what i mean